# Block calls Blackberry and remove Missed Call notification

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am writing a call blocker application. I am blocking the calls successfully, but now I want one more thing:

When blocking the call, I have a notification "One New Missed Call" on the device. I want to remove the missed call notification and remove the call from the call logs.

Can anyone guide me on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you can delete call log entries calling [`PhoneLogs.deleteCall`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/phonelogs/PhoneLogs.html#deleteCall%28int,%20long%29), but due to bugs in the OS this can get tricky. About the notification, I've never tried so I don't know.

Comment: Well how to solve the bugs in the OS in a single code? Tried Thread.sleep and didn't work